# Chrome open bookmark folder in new window via command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, bookmarks

Is it possible to do the "Open all (x) in New Window" [bookmark context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgBka.jpg) via command line?

Like starting Chrome and have it open all the bookmarks in a specific folder?

Comment: Very interested in this, too.

Comment: I'm also very interested in this.